# Common logger settings in Python logging dictConfig

Tags: python, logging

I use `logging.config.dictConfig` in my python application:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,

    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            """ MY_FORMATTER_SETTINGS """
        },
    },

    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/mylogger.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },

    'loggers': {  
        'logger1': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'logger2': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
       'logger3': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },  
        'logger4': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },  
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

Then I create loggers in some modules via `logger = logging.getLogger("logger1")` etc, and use them, for example `logger.info("Some info")`, without any additional configuration.
I like it, but only thing I want to optimize is `loggers` setting, by providing some common(or default?) value for all loggers. Is it possible?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you define a root logger in your "loggers" section?

```
'loggers': {
        #root logger  
        '': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        # other loggers
        ...
}
```

The root logger contains the default log settings, and specifiy additional loggers for the special cases.

Comment: Touching root logger this way is sub-optimal. This solution will channel over debug spams from _all_ upstream libraries the app uses.  see this post: https://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2017/08/06/understanding-pythons-logging-module/